# 404 error in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

when i tried to make an ajax call to webAPI using the following code, most of the time it is returning 404 error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    method: "get",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: { "a": a, "b": b, "date": date in yyyy-mm-dd},
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    timeout: g_TimeOut,
    success: function (data) {
       //success
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        var strResponse = "";
        strResponse = ajaxExceptionHandling(xhr, ajaxOptions);
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

The same thing when i tried to call in restclient as

```
Url?a=a&b=b&date=yyyy-mm-dd
```

it gives correct data. can you please correct, if i missed anything.

request and response headers are

## Request

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
 Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
 Accept: */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

## Response

```
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Expires: -1 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 07:55:28 GMT 
Content-Length: 10701
```

Comment: your datatype is dataType: 'json' ,so check if your incoming data is json type or not

Comment: data coming from the server is in json format.

Comment: could you suggest what could be the reasons for 404 error in ajax requests?

Comment: are you cross domain, I think you may need to use jsonp instead of json.

Comment: be sure your serice get json data

Comment: yes, it is cross domain, but all other get methods are also the same, and they are working fine.

Comment: @user3386468 Its hard to say the reason without seeing the server side code.I can help you if it is in java

Comment: @sakir when i tried from browser it dispalyed as json. is there any other way to identify the return type of the service.

Comment: `jsonp` should be there as this is cross domain request and you need to check if the cors are enabled from that url.

Comment: dear Jai,  there is other get methods which are working fine within same servce. for all i had used json.

Comment: it seems that your server side not configured as the data get json.Becasue u get the right data when u write this (Url?a=a&b=b&date=yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 data: JSON.stringify( {"Url":{ "a": a, "b": b, "date": date in yyyy-mm-dd}})
```

and remove this part

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: Dear @sakir, i tried this. still am getting 404 error